# Jquery datatable - freeze a row on sort

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable. On sort I need to keep a particular row freezed.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgGKD/20/)**

Html:

```
<table id="testTable">
    <thead>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var table;

(function () {
    var firstData = "<tr class='special'>" +
        "<td>" +
        "cellSpecial1" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        "cellSpecial2" +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" +
        "cell11" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        "cell12" +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" +
        "cell21" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        "cell22" +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    debugger;
    $(firstData).appendTo($('#testTable'));
    table = $('#testTable').DataTable({                
        aoRowDefs: [{
        bSortable: false,
        aTargets: ['special']
        }]
    });
    //new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can loop through the rows using this code and leave out the row required -

```
 $('#testTable').children().each(function(i,e)  {

      if( $(e).children().first().text() == 'Special' ) {
       } else {
           //sort the other rows
        }

  });
```

Comment: But sorting is internally handled by datatable plugin . :)

Comment: if you can't find an option in the plugin then you have to do your way or it's the sad plugin highway